# Не работает приложение с подсчетом шагов, скорее проблема в LocationManager

Tags: android, locationmanager

1. Написал приложение , которое должно подсчитывать пройденные мили, но у меня оно не работает. Тестирую приложение на реальном устройстве и передача геоданных включена и разрешение в приложении вкл.

   ```
   LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       return;
   }
   locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, listener);
   ```

   Скорее всего проблема заключается  именно в этом куске кода, в самом низу я скину полный код. В книге нет этого условия, но   оно обязательно  нужно, покопался и узнал, что причина в API 23 и это условие обязательно. Так же  в манифесте  у меня есть эта строка.

   `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

   Код службы :

   ```
   public class OdometerService extends Service {
     private final IBinder binder = new OdometerBinder();
     private static double distanceInMeters;
     private static Location lastLocation = null;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
           @Override
           public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
               if (lastLocation == null) {
                   lastLocation = location;
               }
               distanceInMeters += location.distanceTo(lastLocation);
               lastLocation = location;
           }

           @Override
           public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
           }

           @Override
           public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
           }

           @Override
           public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle bundle) {
           }

       };
       LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           return;
       }
       locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, listener);
   }

   public class OdometerBinder extends Binder {
       OdometerService getOdometer() {
           return OdometerService.this;
       }
   }

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return binder;
   }
   public double getMiles() {
       return this.distanceInMeters / 1609.344;
   }
   }
   ```

   И код активности:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private OdometerService odometer;
     private boolean bound = false;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       watchMileage();
   }

   private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
       @Override
       public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder binder) {
           OdometerService.OdometerBinder odometerBinder =
                   (OdometerService.OdometerBinder) binder;
           odometer = odometerBinder.getOdometer();
           bound = true;
       }

       @Override
       public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
           bound = false;
       }
   };

   private void watchMileage() {
       final TextView distanceView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
       handler.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               double distance = 0.0;
               if (odometer != null) {
                   distance = odometer.getMiles();
               }
               String distanceStr = String.format("%1$,.2f km", distance);
               distanceView.setText(distanceStr);
               handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, OdometerService.class);
       bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       if (bound) {
           unbindService(connection);
           bound = false;
       }
   }
   }
   ```